Get object on openpages rest API by name
I need to get an SOXIssue type object using the field "name" I thought about use search route but the documentation for this route is bad. I'm using Version 8.3.0 of API, does anyone knows how to get there?
I tried to use search route by can't figure out how to with the official documentation.

You can do two things:

Find the resource using the /grc/api/query endpoint. Look for it by querying: /grc/api/query?q=SELECT [Resource ID] FROM [SOXIssue] WHERE [Name] = ''
Go back to the /grc/api/contents/ with your found resource.

You can get most properties you need from the main Query you did before however. But if you need to do things like access /auditlog or other resources, you now should have the Resource ID.
